# Examples of complexes of modules for wich homomorphisms "homological" implies "homotopic"

Tags: homological-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $V$ and $V^\prime$ - complexes of modules over ring $A$, and $f, g$ - homomorphisms $V\rightarrow V^\prime$.

> I am interested in various conditions on $A, V, V^\prime$: ($f$ and $g$ are homological) $\Rightarrow$ ($f$ and $g$ are homotopic).

(I knew one example: $A$ - hereditary algebra and $V, V^\prime$ - complexes of projective modules, bounded from the right. But recently I understood that in this case it's not true that ($f$ and $g$ are homological) $\Rightarrow$ ($f$ and $g$ are homotopic))

Comment: I assume that by "homological" you mean "homologous"

Comment: I mean that maps $H_n(f)=H_n(g)$ for all $n$. The term "homological" is used in the book Y.A. Drozd, V.V Kirichenko "Finite-Dimensional Algebras".

Comment: Some of the discussion at mathoverflow.net/questions/8974/chain-homotopy-why-duud-and-not-duvd/ is relevant.

Answer (score 5):

This question relates to a very complicated problem known as **Freyd's generating hypothesis**. The problem was first posed for the stable homotopy category but it can be extended to more general triangulated categories, such as the derived category $D(R)$ of a ring $R$. In this context the hypothesis (which may or may not be satisfied, depending on $R$) says that your $\Rightarrow$ is satisfied whenever the complexes are (quasi-isomorphic to) bounded complexes of f.g. projectives. Keir H. Lockridge proved (JPAA, 2007) that for $R$ commutative this is true if and only if $R$ is von Neumann regular. You can look at this problem in other contexts (e.g. modular representation theory) to get more examples and counterexamples.

Comment: Sorry, but can you give some simple examples?

Comment: Don't you find simple enough what I've said?

Comment: Well, it would be nice to see an example of a pair of complexes over a non-vnr ring (e.g. over Z) and a pair of maps between them that are homologous but not homotopic.

Comment: Over $\mathbb Z$ it is very easy, take two abelian groups $A$ and $B$ with non-vanishing $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$. This abelian group classifies homotopy classes $A\rightarrow B[1]$, and all these maps obviously induce the trivial morphism in homology by dimension reasons. I took this as being "non research level".